# How to create two column output from a single column

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I am guessing this is a noob question so please bear with me. I have a column in a mySQL table that contains both first name and last name plus other data (see table below).

```
fid | uid | value
 5  |  1  | John
 6  |  1  | Doe
 7  |  1  | some other data
 5  |  2  | Jane
 6  |  2  | Doe
 7  |  2  | some other data
```

What I would like to do is create a query where I split out the first and last names into their own columns for reporting purposes (like shown below).

```
First Name | Last Name
  John     |   Doe
  Jane     |   Doe
```

I haven't seen this question asked before here nor have I been able to Google (perhaps using the wrong keywords). I assume this is relatively simple but it is eluding me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to join the table to itself with something like this:

```
select first_name.value, last_name.value
from your_table first_name
join your_table last_name on first_name.uid = last_name.uid
where first_name.fid = 5
  and last_name.fid  = 6
```

You can join a table to itself or join the same table multiple times as long as you use a different alias for each instance of the table.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I didn't realize that you can link the same table to itself. I marked yours as the accepted answer since you provided a good explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The self join isn't necessary:

```
  SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN yt.fid = 5 THEN yt.value ELSE NULL END) AS firstname,
         MAX(CASE WHEN yt.fid = 6 THEN yt.value ELSE NULL END) AS lastname
    FROM YOUR_TABLE yt
GROUP BY yt.uid
```

Comment: This is why I like this site so much, I am always learn something new.

Comment: Why is this better than the self join approach? Is the increased complexity of this query (compared to the simplicity of the self join) justifiable in any way? I will up vote if you provide a valid explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @buritos: A self join means two passes over the table -- the `GROUP BY` means one.  I don't know how to respond to the use of aggregates/`GROUP BY` being "increased complexity" - most would say a JOIN is equally complex, if not more so.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a self join on uid like so:

```
select 
  t1.value as 'First Name', 
  t2.value as 'Last Name' 
from 
  <table_name> t1 join 
  <table_name> t2 on t1.uid = t2.uid 
where 
  t1.fid = 5 and 
  t2.fid = 6;
```

To speed things up, and if it's not already there, consider adding an index on fid like so:

```
create index FID_IDX on <table_name> (fid);
```

this will prevent mysql from using a join buffer to resolve the query and it will go through the index instead.

However, the index will slow down your inserts and updates on this table a bit. If write performance is more important than read then do not add it.