# MySQL showing the last two months sales

Tags: mysql

I am trying to extract a report that shows the last two full calendar months sales as per the following format:

```
Customer           August 2013    September 2014
Company A                1,250             2,543
Company B                4,245             1,423
Company C                1,432             1,642
```

I have a table with the customer and individual transaction with a cost. I am fine getting this out but have no idea how to get two columns next to each other.

```
select customers.customer as Customer,
       sum(job.price) as August_2014 
from job,customers
where customers.cust_id=job.customer 
and
job.collect_date between '2014-08-01' and '2014-08-31'
group by customer
order by August_2014 desc 
limit 0,10
```

Thanks for any help.

John

Comment: Can you give us an example, of the output you want.

Comment: @arun hopefully you can see the sort of thing I am after

Comment: by "two columns next to each other" you mean August and September?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345737/how-to-create-two-column-output-from-a-single-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use case expressions inside the SUM() function, like this:

```
SELECT
      customers.customer AS Customer
    , SUM(case when job.collect_date >= '2014-08-01' and  job.collect_date < '2014-09-01' THEN job.price ELSE 0 END)     AS August_2014
    , SUM(case when job.collect_date >= '2014-09-01' and  job.collect_date < '2014-10-01' THEN job.price ELSE 0 END)     AS September_2014
FROM job
INNER JOIN customers ON customers.cust_id = job.customer
WHERE  ( job.collect_date >= '2014-08-01' AND job.collect_date < '2014-10-01' )
GROUP BY
      customers.customer
ORDER BY
      August_2014 DESC
limit 0,10
;
```

I changed the join syntax, explicit joins like this are strongly recommended.

---

Also note I have changed the method for "date ranges". Just do NOT trust "between" for this. Always use the method shown above and you will not have any gaps or overlaps in the data (i.e. your  numbers will be accurate).

( date_field >= lower_date_here AND date_field < higher_date_here )

As you can see, the "higher date" is one day more than your original, that's because we use LESS THAN on the higher date

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  customers.customer AS Customer,
  MONTH(job.collect_date) AS Month,
  sum(job.price) AS SumPrice 
FROM 
  job,
  customers
WHERE 
  customers.cust_id = job.customer
GROUP BY 
  customer,
  MONTH(job.collect_date)
```

You cannot do the `order by` price anymore. I'm sure you can make the table yourself?

No, people cannot write PHP themselves, and want an example:

```
// the sql command  
$sql = "SELECT 
          customers.customer AS Customer,
          MONTH(job.collect_date) AS Month,
          sum(job.price) AS SumPrice 
        FROM 
          job,
          customers
        WHERE 
          customers.cust_id = job.customer
        GROUP BY 
          customer,
          MONTH(job.collect_date)";
// fetching data        
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) 
{
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {
    extract($row);
    $data[$Customer][$Month] = $SumPrice;
  }
  $result->close();   
}  
// render
foreach($data as $customer => $prices)
{
  echo $customer;
  foreach($prices as $month => $price)
  {
    echo ' '.$price;
  }
  echo '<br>';
}
```

Note that the table rendering is the very basic, but it given you the idea, you need to work a bit on it to make it nicer. This will work regardless of which months are in the database. The main advantage is the simplicity of the SQL query.

Comment: i think he wants the months next to each other on the same row.

Comment: This can't be the answer as he wants two columns in a same row about price,  which is not achieved in this query.

Comment: Well, you need PHP to make the table. This is so basic I left it out. But I'll add it in for those that don't know how to do that. Mind you, the question didn't mention any PHP...

Comment: Hi all, I am after 2 columns showing the different months.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i think i do understand what it does.  it lists each month per row... August in its own row and September in its own.  He wants August and Spetember in the same row, each in their own column.  At least thats what I deduce that he wants from his question.

Comment: I added the PHP code to make the rows. Note that you might have to add in some extra code for month that have no data.